# Simplest way to expose my custom data from WCF Data Service?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have some data in files (not database). What is the simplest way to expose it as a WCF Data Service?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to use the WCF WEB API, [look here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api).